# Multiple Promise.reject with es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I m actually coding some functions using chained promises and I m having some trouble dealing with them.

Actually, here's the anti-pattern that I want to avoid :

```
  return promise.then((res)=>{
    return promise2.then((result)=>{
      return result;
    },(error)=>{
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
  },(err)=>{
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
```

I tried refactoring it the following :

```
  return promise.then((res)=>{
    return promise2;
  },(err)=>{
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }).then((result)=>{
    return result;
  },(error)=>{
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

The fact is that I don't know at all of my rejected promises will act. It seems that my unit tests are all breaking after this refactor and I don't understand why. Maybe the behaviour...

In fact, does my (error) callback contain the (err) rejected value, or will it break completely and return the promise directly ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : okay I ll try with another example . Let's imagine that I need to make some arithmetic opeartions asynchronously by catching each possible error, at each possible level

```
  asyncAddition(5, -5).then((res)=>{
    return asyncDivide(100, res);
  },(err)=>{
    return Promise.reject('ERROR, you cant divide by 0');
  }).then((res)=>{
    return asyncMultiply(res, 10);
  }).then((res)=>{
    return res;
  },(err)=>{
    return Promise.reject('An error occured, number result is over 1000 ');
  });
```

Does the first promise rejected will break all the other in the chain ? Or will it continue ?

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 2):

An `(error)=>{return Promise.reject(error);}` error callback is about as useless as a `(result)=>{return result;}` success callback. Used with `then`, it's an identity. You can simply omit them:

```
return promise.then(res => promise2);
```

> It seems that my unit tests are all breaking after this refactor and I don't understand why.

The two snippets you are posted will have equivalent results. Their exact flow might be a bit different, e.g. `Promise.reject` being called twice in the second example when `promise` is rejected, but if both `promise` and `promise2` are standard promises with Promises/A+ semantics then this must not matter.

> okay I ll try with another example . Let's imagine that I need to make some operations asynchronously by catching each possible error, at each possible level

Yes, it does make quite a difference here. Catching errors on multiple levels, and treating them distinctly, will have different outcomes. An error handler will handle *all* errors on a promise, that is, in the complete chain above it (but not in the `scuccess` callback of the same `then` call, see [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for details).

I believe you are actually looking for

```
asyncAddition(5, -5).then(res => {
    return asyncDivide(100, res).catch(err =>{
        throw new Error('ERROR, you cant divide by 0');
    });
}).then(res => {
    return asyncMultiply(res, 10).catch(err => {
        throw new Error('An error occured, number result is over 1000');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use   .Promise.all(arrofPromises).then(function() {
    console.log("all is ok");
});

Comment: @TalAvissar: Because I have no idea what OP is actually doing. Yes, `Promise.all` might be a better solution to his actual problem, or it might not. I've just posted code that is equivalent to the one in the question, whether that makes sense or not.